# How to replace li in jquery mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

```
    var $areas = $('#ulArs'); //To take the control of ulArs
    $areas.empty();
    $areas.append('<li id="li1" data-role="list-divider"></li>');
    for (var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++) 
    {
     li = "<li id='home_nav' style='white-space:normal'></li>";
    }
     $areas.append(li).trigger('create');
     $areas.listview('refresh');
```

I m creating dynamic UL with multiple li.i want to replace one particular li on change of checkbox without refreshing.can it be possible in jquery mobile?

Comment: What have you tried so far? In what scope is the code you posted? What exactly do you mean by `replace one particular li`? Also you are possibly giving multiple LI elements the same ID which is invalid in the HTML spec (inside the `for` loop). I'd recommend changing the ID attribute to CLASS.

Answer (score 1):

As fas as I know , you definitely should call refresh method. But what is a problem? According to [this information('Updating lists' section)](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/lists/docs-lists.html) : "Note that the refresh() method only affects new nodes appended to a list. This is done for performance reasons. Any list items already enhanced will be ignored by the refresh process."

Answer (score 1):

```
var $areas = $('#ulArs'); //To take the control of ulArs
$areas.empty();
$areas.append('<li id="li1" data-role="list-divider"></li>');
var li = '';
for (var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++) {
  li += '<li class="home_nav" id="home_nav-' + i + '" style="white-space:normal"></li>';
}
$areas.append(li).trigger('create');
$areas.listview('refresh');
```

you can refer to a `li` with `id`, for example:

```
$('#home_nav-0')
```

or adding any other information the element `li`, for example `data`